# Is it possible to get the address of the underlying storage for an atomic_int?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, c++11, atomic

I want to use an [`std::atomic_int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) with the [`futex`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) linux function.

However, the `futex` function requires an address location, and I am uncertain about the correctness of just using the address of the `atomic_int` object.

Therefore, I wonder if it is possible to get the address of the underlying storage for an `atomic_int`, so I can then pass it to the `futex` call.

Answer (score 1):

Portably, no. Realistically, an `atomic_int` is probably just `sizeof(int)` bytes of memory like a regular `int` on any modern C++ implementation. If `sizeof(std::atomic<int>) == sizeof(int)`, go for broke and just pass its address to `futex` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not.

In manual

```
int futex(int *uaddr, int op, int val, const struct timespec *timeout,
    int *uaddr2, int val3);

The uaddr argument needs to point to an aligned integer which stores the counter.  The operation to execute  is  passed via the op argument, along with a value val.
```

Your `atomic_int` should be aligned.

In gcc 4.7.2 (which on Fedora 18), file: `/usr/include/c++/4.7.2/bits/atomic_base.h`

```
// Base types for atomics.
template<typename _IntTp>
  struct __atomic_base;
...
/// atomic_int
typedef __atomic_base<int>                    atomic_int;
...
template<typename _ITp>
struct __atomic_base
{
private:
  typedef _ITp      __int_type;

  __int_type        _M_i;

// some operations
...
```

`atomic_int` is just a wrapper of data `__int_type        _M_i;` where `__int_type` is the template parameter you pass in. So it's an integer. And the struct is not guaranteed aligned in cross platform.