# writing to std::atomic after converting to char*

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast, memory-layout, stdatomic

Sorry if my doubt is too naive. But I have a difficulty in typecasting `std::atomic` to `char*` type. Is casting from `std::atomic to char` is valid?

Can I write to such type casted variable. I am sure that there will be no multithreaded reads/writes while a thread tries to write into the variable.(I understand that, there is no need for using atomics when there will be no concurrent access on this variable)

```
std::atomic<uint8_t>* data_;
char *data = reinterpret_cast<char*>(data_);
*data |= mask;
```

Is it safe to do?

EDIT:
 I am not sure if its worth mentioning. In my code,

```
char *raw;
// variable raw is allocated
std::atomic<uint8_t>* data_ = reinterpret_cast<std::atomic<uint8_t>*>(raw);
```

The above is how the `std::atomic< uint8_t>` is created (as char and type casted to std::atomic type).

Thanks :)

Comment: The answer you linked does not mention `std::atomic` at all. You can't even cast between `std::atomic<uint8_t>*` and `uint8_t*`.

Comment: @molbdnilo But we can `reinterpret_cast` a pointer to an object of any type into `char*`, right?

Comment: @DanielLangr You can cast, but that doesn't mean that you can do anything meaningful with the result.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes u re right. That link was a wrong reference i was looking for. Removed it

Comment: The link in a previous version of your question shows that it is safe to write to `std::uint8_t`.  However `std::atomic<std:uint8_t>` is not a `std::uint8_t`.  It is a very different thing with potentially different layout and alignment.

Comment: Maybe, you should describe the problem you are trying to solve by these constructs than to ask about your solution (XY).

Comment: @MartinBonner In practice if the representation of `std::atomic<std:uint8_t>` is not the same as `std:uint8_t`, you probably should use a different tool.

Comment: @curiousguy Not so!  On many platforms it is only possible to operate atomically on an aligned full-word.  So a `std::atomic<std::uint8_t>` will have some wasted bits.  Depending on where the wasted bits are, the cast the OP asks about may well write to them rather than to the actual value.  Further, the edit shows how he obtains the atomic in the first place - and it is quite likely not to be suitably aligned.

Comment: @MartinBonner On which platforms?

Comment: @curiousguy Well  LDREX and STREX were introduced in ARMv6T2, and the \*B versions didn't appear until ARMv6K.

Comment: @MartinBonner: pure load and pure store of a byte are still atomic, and you can still implement a byte atomic RMW using word LL/SC by just merging the change in the appropriate word.  The commit of the whole word only succeeds if the cache line hasn't been touched by other threads, so it's safe.  But yes, it might be preferable to pad the size of an `atomic<char>` to the CPU's native atomic-RMW size and save an instruction or two inside the LL/SC retry loop.

Comment: But really, IDK why the OP would ever want this.  If you want a non-atomic RMW for performance, do a separate atomic load and store.  If you have parts of your program that don't need atomicity for the object, use C++20 [`std::atomic_ref  foo(myvar)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_ref) for the parts that do need to be atomic.  (But beware of 8-byte objects on 32-bit platforms that are under-aligned for double-word CAS; naive atomic_ref implementations will not actually be atomic in that case)

Comment: @MartinBonner: GCC for ARM chooses to make `atomic<uint8_t>` lock-free and 1 byte, but using a helper function instead of inlining a word LL/SC retry loop.  https://godbolt.org/z/9J-xFy.  Notice that even with `gcc -march=armv6` (not k) where we get a `bl  __sync_fetch_and_or_1`, it still returns `1` for `return data_.is_lock_free();`.  The gotcha you propose is certainly a possible implementation choice, but it isn't present in real ABIs on ARM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's safe at all. The C++ Standard does not guarantee `std::atomic<uint8_t>` to be *lock-free*. If it is not, then there might be, e.g.,  a *mutex* member variable stored in every `std::atomic<uint8_t>` object starting at its first byte. In such a case, your command `*data |= mask;` would manipulate a bit of this mutex, which might completely break its internal implementation.

---

This might be also a relevant question: [Is it possible to get the address of the underlying storage for an atomic_int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21104420/580083).

Comment: @krithikaGopalakrisnan It's even worse now. While you can `reinterpret_cast` a pointer to an object of any type into `char*`, the opposite is not true.